# JfreeChart XYPlot freezing after zoom in/out

Tags: java, graphics, jfreechart

In [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDynamicDataDemo.htm) demo application, XYPlot is drawn with dynamic data. With every new data the graphic slides to left dynamically. But the problem is if you `zoom in` or `zoom out` on XYPlot the graphic stops sliding and new data can not be seen on XYPlot.

Is this a bug for JFreeChart or is it default behaviour for XYPlot ?

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior. To enable auto range behavior again, right-click inside the plot and select: `Auto Range ► Both Axes`.

[image]